# DispForm.aspx looks different for different items for the same sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SharePoint list and a DispForm.apx associated with it. whenever any item is clicked in the list, the dispForm opens.

The issue that we are facing is that the dispForm.aspx looks a bit different for different items. Everything is same except that for some the view ribbon is enabled and for some it is disabled(ie, greyed out).
Any idea as to why it is behaving in this way since the same form is being used for all the items?

I am new to SharePoint so any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

[the one working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guj9x.png)

[the one with greyed out ribbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXOhe.png)

Comment: Have you checked your permissions on those items?

Comment: yes I have checked and the permission is same for all the items.